# Hook WM_POINTERDOWN and WM_POINTERUP globally

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to listen to screen touches and track locations using WM_POINTERDOWN and WM_POINTERUP globally (not just on my own app). How can I do this globally? Is there something analogous to global mouse hooks?

**Update.** It seems the only way to do this is to use a C++ Dll registering for  WH_GETMESSAGE or WH_CALLWNDPROC.

Comment: There is no dedicated hook for that like there is for the mouse and keyboard.  You need the kind of hook that you cannot write in C#.  That's usually where it ends.

Comment: By that you mean I need C++ and WH_GETMESSAGE or WH_CALLWNDPROC?

Comment: You already know the answer, no good reason to leave it out of your question.

Comment: Hans, do you know if a CLR Class Library in C++ would work or does it have to be non-managed?